# How to Pass a C# variable to JavaScript Variable in Universal Windows Application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I have a variable called **"cb"** in my C# class file, I want to use it in my HTML page using JavaScript function.

Here Is my C# code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string str = "ms-appx-web:///homepage.html";
        wview.Navigate(new Uri(str, UriKind.Absolute));

    }
    public string cb = "";
    public async void init(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string val = e.Value;
        if (val == "picture")
        {
            try
            {
                cb = await ocrchild.picture();
                Debug.WriteLine("Image saved at :- " + cb);                    
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my html code, I want that **cb** to be in stored in **i4** variable, Can you help me with this?

```
<script>
    function CallNative()
    {
        var i1=document.getElementById("id1").checked;
        var i2=document.getElementById("id2").checked;
        var i3 = document.getElementById("id3").checked;
        var i4 = "";

        if(i1== true)
        {
            window.external.notify("picture");
        }
        if (i2 == true) {
            window.external.notify("ocr");
        }
        if (i3 == true) {
            window.external.notify("base64");
        }
        document.getElementById("id4").value = i4;
    };


</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is easly accessed in javascript.
you have add hidden field or label in aspx page and set a value in cs page.


another option if you use html page then you will call ajax method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But can You explain this more clearly

Comment: Please you clearyfy that you have html page or aspx page.

Comment: i have html page

Comment: you should use query string .                                                                                           e.g  htttp://myhtmlpahe.html?id=123

Comment: can you give me the exact syntax for that

Comment: var url = window.location.search;
url = url.replace("?", ''); // remove the ?
alert(url);                                                                                                           call in javascript tag into html page